# prototype - Replace & with &amp;

Tags: magento, prototypejs

I am working with Magento which uses the prototype javascript library. Unfortunately some of the client's data (being fed from point of sale system in to Magento) has `&` in the html instead of `&amp;`.

Can anyone help with a method to change all instances of `&` in the html to `&amp;` for validation purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`escapeHTML`](http://prototypejs.org/api/string/escapeHTML), part of Prototype's [`String`](http://prototypejs.org/api/string) library.